# Shiny: Send an resize event when UI element gets resized

Tags: r, shiny

I have a UI element like

```
fluidRow(column(12, rbokehOutput("linePlots")) )
```

the server.R returns

```
grid_plot(p1,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE, same_axes=FALSE,width=1500)
```

Which is a rbokeh figure. When the window resizes i would like to return an alternative grid_plot with a different value for ncol. Is this possible in Shiny?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you can create a Shiny binding in the page Javascript and call a R function on the window re-size event. Combine this  `renderUI` and you can bind DOM events to R functions that update the UI.

```
require(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(HTML('
        $(window).resize(function(event){
          var w = $(this).width();
          var h = $(this).height();
          var obj = {width: w, height: h};
          Shiny.onInputChange("pltChange", obj);
        });
      '))
    ),
    fluidRow( column(12, uiOutput('ui')) ),
    fluidRow( column(12, textOutput('txt')) )
  )),
  server = shinyServer( function(input,output,session){
    data <- list(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),main="no resize")

    observeEvent(input$pltChange,{
      output$ui <- renderUI({
        plotOutput("linePlots") 
      })

      str <- sprintf('Window height: %d, Window width %d', input$pltChange$height, input$pltChange$width)
      output$txt <- renderText({
        print(str)
      })
      data$main <- str
      output$linePlots <- renderPlot({ plot(data,main=data$main) })
    })
  })
)
```

This example create a `plotOutput` and fills it in once the window is re-sized. This is just an example of the basic principle of this. Since you haven't provided a reproducible example maybe this can help you get an idea on how to do it.

Comment: Indeed it does. I read your answer very late but it's exactly what I need. Much thanks

Comment: Really nice example code in this answer!